# Dynamically create and setup scenarios

Tags: scala, gatling

I'd like to dynamically create and setUp gatling scenarios in a `for` loop to load test a webservice.

Therefore I tried the following (shortened):

```
class RecordedSimulation extends Simulation {

  val httpProtocol = http
    .baseURL("http://127.0.0.1")

  val overallUsers = 1000

  val methods: Map[String, Double] = Map(
    "FindContact" -> 0.6,
    "FindAddress" -> 0.3,
    "FindNumber" -> 0.1
  )

  for ((methodname, probability) <- methods) {
    val scen = scenario(methodname)
      .exec(http(methodname)
        .get("/contactservice")
        .queryParam("method", methodname))

    setUp(scen.inject(constantUsersPerSec(overallUsers * probability) during (60 seconds))).protocols(httpProtocol)
  }
}
```

If I try running this simulation nothing happens: No simulation is started, also no error appears.

So my question is if it is even possible to dynamically create and setUp gatling scenarios. Am I missing something or doing something wrong?

---

Why do I want to do it dynamically anyway?

Well I have a lot of pretty similar methods to test and I'd like to avoid copy/pasting the same scenario over and over again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem myself. [This gist](https://gist.github.com/mburrows02/b3b98687ac8acdded39e) got me in the right direction.

It seems **you can call the `setUp` method only once**. So I'm  putting my scenarios in an ArraySeq and calling `setUp` with this ArraySeq as a parameter:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ArraySeq
import io.gatling.core.structure.PopulationBuilder

class RecordedSimulation extends Simulation {

  val httpProtocol = http
    .baseURL("http://127.0.0.1")

  val overallUsers = 1000

  val methods: Map[String, Double] = Map(
    "FindContact" -> 0.6,
    "FindAddress" -> 0.3,
    "FindNumber" -> 0.1
  )

  def scnList() = {
    var scnList = new ArraySeq[PopulationBuilder](methods.size)
    var i = 0
    for ((methodname, probability) <- methods) {
      var scen = scenario(methodname)
        .exec(http(methodname)
          .get("/contactservice")
          .queryParam("method", methodname))
        .inject(constantUsersPerSec(overallUsers * probability) during (60 seconds) randomized)

      scnList(i) = scen
      i = i + 1
    }
    scnList
  }

  setUp(scnList: _*).protocols(httpProtocol)
}
```

Note: As discussed in the comments, `ArraySeq` is abstract in recent versions of Scala. As keylogger suggests, use an `Array` instead.

Comment: Using Gatling 3.5.1 , scala version 2.13.3 , it complains about this line `var scnList = new ArraySeq[PopulationBuilder](methods.size)`  --- `class ArraySeq is abstract; cannot be instantiated`.  Using Gatling 3.3.1 , scala version 2.12.10 , it builds fine.

Comment: @keylogger Yeah, seems like the API changed there, `ArraySeq` [is now abstract in Scala 2.13](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.5/scala/collection/mutable/ArraySeq.html), while [it was not in 2.12](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.10/scala/collection/mutable/ArraySeq.html). Maybe you can use another collection instead, e.g., an [`ArrayBuffer`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.5/scala/collection/mutable/ArrayBuffer.html)

Comment: Yeah, I tried `ArrayBuffer` and IntelliJ complained about this line `setUp(scnList: _*)` . I can't remember the error message tho. Something related to `_*` can't grab the elements. Then I just changed it to plain `Array` and now it works fine again. Thanks for putting your solution here. It helps :)